# can someone help me fix this Picker error

Tags: java, codenameone

I am using Picker component is codename one, it was working properly before as shown in 1st screenshot, its showing the full string.
But in 2nd screenshot, its not showing some alphabets.

Screenshot 1: !https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIJdz.jpg

Screenshot 2: !https://i.stack.imgur.com/ck8ql.jpg

```
Picker pcle = new Picker();
Accordion acle=new Accordion();
pcle.setType(Display.PICKER_TYPE_STRINGS);
pcle.setStrings(
"Picking up a trash",
"Cleaning up a beach     "+"10",
"Cleaning up a park     "+"10",
"Tidying up the table after eating in a restaurant.     "+"5",
"Joining a clean up operation     "+"20"
);
pcle.setSelectedString("Select a Deed from Bottom of Screen");
acle.addContent("Cleaning", pcle);
```

where 'pcle' is my Picker,
'acle' is my Accordion

it is supposed to show whole string, but its not showing.

Comment: I dont think your screen shot links are working.

Comment: Is it not redirecting you to image file? coz In my System its working fine.

Comment: Now it is working, for some reason last night they just sent me to a page showing some random images.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a regression due to the fix made here: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2774

I suggest commenting on the issue so it can be resolved by the upcoming Friday update.